# SQL row in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have this SQL query

```
SELECT COUNT(*)*100/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tickets WHERE status = 'closed')
FROM tickets 
WHERE closed_at <= due_at 
UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*)*100/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tickets WHERE status = 'closed') 
FROM tickets 
WHERE closed_at > due_at;
```

and it returns this

```
ROW 1 - 35
ROW 2 - 47
```

but I need the return like this:

```
 1 | 2 |
35  47
```

I need the returns in columns, not rows.

Thanks.

Comment: This was asked too many times, just search for PIVOT, UNPIVOT SQL TABLES

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN closed_at <= due_at THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       ), 
       (SUM(CASE WHEN closed_at > due_at THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       )
FROM tickets ;
```

It seems strange that you are filtering on `status = 'closed'` in the denominator, but not in the numerator.  If `status = closed` should be the filter for both, then you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN closed_at <= due_at THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END),
       AVG(CASE WHEN closed_at > due_at THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END)
FROM tickets
WHERE status = 'closed';
```